# Protractor: How to locate a sibling of a given element?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, protractor, ui-testing

```
<div>
   <a href='...'>LINK</a>
   <img class='image' />
</div>
<div>
   ...
</div>
```

I want to get a protractor element for the `img` tag with `image` class. I already know the link text 'LINK'. In other words, "How do I locate a sibling of a given element?".

The first line of the code could look like this:

```
browser.findElement(by.linkText('LINK'))
```

Any ideas?

Thanks & Cheers

Comment: Could you catch the parent? because elementFinder can be chained to find within a known parent: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementfinderelement but it seems to me that this feature is missing and you can ask on Protractor Github if there's a workaround or suggest a pull request ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks for the inspiration. Here's my solution, not the one I was hoping for, but it works:

```
element(by.css('???')).element(by.xpath('..')).element(by.css('???')).click();
```

The chaining and the by.xpath, which allows to get back to the parent are the keys of the solution.

Comment: In case other people reach this page: [Protractor style guide](https://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide) asks to never use XPath. But in our case, to find a sibling, it seems that there is currently no better solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I actually implement on a Page Object:

```
  this.widgets['select-status'] = this.ids['select-status']
      .element(by.xpath('following-sibling::div[1]'));
  this.widgets['select-status.dropdown'] = element(by.css('.btn-group.bootstrap-select.open'));
```

The page is based on Bootstrap along with Bootstrap Select. Anyways, we traverse the DOM along the `following-sibling` axis. Refer to XPATH specification for yourself.

Comment: it worked for me as well. i.e. 
`var result = cols.all(by.cssContainingText('span', 'MY TEXT'));
var sibElem = result.all(by.xpath("following-sibling::div[1]")).first();`

Answer (score 0):

Using Xpath selectors is not a better choice as it slows down the element finding mechanism.

I have designed a plugin to address this specific issues: [protractor-css-booster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-css-booster)

The plugin provides some handly locators to find out siblings in a better way and most importantly with CSS selector.

using this plugin, you can directly use:

```js
var elem = await element(by.cssContainingText('a','link text')).nextSibling();

elem.click(); //proceed with your work
```

or, use this as by-locator

```js
var elem = element(by.cssContainingText('a','link text')).element(by.followingSibling('img'));
```

You can always checkout the other handy methods available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-css-booster)...

Now, you can find web elements such as:

1. Finding Grand Parent Element
2. Finding Parent Element
3. Finding Next Sibling
4. Finding Previous Sibling
5. Finding any Following Sibling
6. Finding First Child Element
7. Finding Last Child Element

And, guess what, everything you can find using  CSS Selectors

Hope, it will help you...